# How can I append NULL onto the end of a string pointer array?

Tags: c, string, malloc, execvp

I am trying to use execvp to execute unix commands with given flags.

My array, argv, might contain these elements:

```
{"ls", "-a"}
```

I am then passing this array to

```
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

How can I safely append *NULL* onto the end of the argv array so execvp will know where to terminate?

Comment: Is the array statically defined, or is it passed to the program as an argument, or are you generating it from user input?

Comment: If he’s taking in a non-NULL-terminated array with no extra room, he’ll have to copy it to an array one element larger, but that’s unlikely?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was indeed generating it off of user input. As I mentioned below, it was an oversight on my end. I forgot to account for the NULL element when calling malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 elements in your array.  Simply allocate three elements instead and set the last one to NULL:

```
char* args[] = {"ls", "-a", NULL};
execvp(path, args);
```

Or, since you mention `malloc()`:

```
char** args = malloc(3 * sizeof args[0]);
args[0] = "ls";
args[1] = "-a";
args[2] = NULL;
execvp(path, args);
free(args);
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `malloc()` return in C

Comment: We do not know if the array that needs modification is allocated by him or something else.

Comment: If he wants to extend an existing array that he did not allocate himself, he will have to allocate a new array and copy the existing values into it.

Comment: It turns out this was simply an oversight on my end. Thank you for the responses. Since I am generating the array based off of user input, I am using a counter variable that matches the amount of commands and/or flags. When calling malloc() I forgot to account for extra element of NULL.

Comment: I know, it's nitpicking, but since beginners copy code, i want to mention that `malloc` could return NULL.